# Power of involutory and special orthogonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, numerical-linear-algebra

Is there a formula to easily compute the power of the following matrix multiplication: $(\mathbf{I}^*\mathbf{A})^n$, where $\mathbf{I}^*=\text{diag}(1,1,\ldots,1,-1,-1)$ is an involutory and special orthogonal matrix?

Comment: Unless $B = I*A$ is nilpotent, we expect to need to find the Jordan normal form of $B$ to do this. Or Jordan-Chevalley, which is similar

Comment: I was looking for a formula explicitly in terms of \mathbf{A}^n